# Build a tabular with a lot of text

Tags: tabularx, multirow, columns

I'm creating a `tabular` that has one `\multirow` column another with very long   titles and the last one with really a lot of text (really a lot).

I have tried already many solutions but no one have worked, the one wich is close to the solution in the next:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c| x | X |}
  \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{Teoría} & Descripción \\
  \hline
 \multirow {4}{\begin{turn}{90}{title}} & long text & really very very very very long text \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

But the last column is smaller than de central one (must be the opposite) and the text doesnt fix in the first column and overflow in the third.

I also tried

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{2cm}C{3cm}X}

\end{tabularx}
```

But it doesn't work either.
I need help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. From your fragments is possible to figured out, what you like to achieve only with help of crystal ball. You are lucky, since it seems that @Mico has one operational  :-)

Comment: @Zarko - Lucky indeed that Sybill Trelwawny didn't destroy all of her crystal balls during the Battle of Hogwarts! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following layout may be close to what you want. Note that it's not necessary to load the `multirow` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c | X | X |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Teoría} & Descripción \\
\hline
 \rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{~vertical title~}
 & long text 
 & really very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! is really usefull, i have other questions  it is possible that the third column is larger than the first? how could I do that ?, on the other hand this table will be several pages can be used in a longtable environment?

Comment: @Isadora - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "larger" in your first question: The third column is already wider than the first, isn't it? (Or are you asking about making column 3 wider than column 2?) Regarding your second question: one can't use the `X` column type in `longtable` environments. Either choose a `p` column type and set the column width manually, or look into the capabilities of the `LTXtable` environment.

Comment: yes,  is just that, the third  column ( column 3 ) wider (twice)  than column 2. I apologize, you may notice my english is not the best one.

Comment: @Isadora - To make column 3 twice as wide as column 2, while continuing to use the `tabularx` framework, write `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c | >{\hsize=0.667\hsize}X  | >{\hsize=1.333\hsize}X |}`. Note that the sum of the `\hsize`s is 2, which is the number of columns of type `X`.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that I could finally use in a Latex in Debian wheezy (a very old version)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{supertabular}{| c | p{4cm} | p{11cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}} & \textbf{Title} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}[-3cm]{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{LONG TITLE}}
 & A Lot of Text   & really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text  \\
\cline{2-3}

& A Lot of Text   & really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text  \\
\cline{2-3}

& A Lot of Text   & really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text  \\
\cline{2-3}

& A Lot of Text   & really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text really a lot of text  \\
\hline

\end{supertabular}
```

i hope may be usefull for some one.